# How to get an array saved in State to show as divs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate an array of streaming services for a new project.

I am new to React, so would like some help.

The code I am using to call everything is:

```
const [streamingState, setStreamingState] = useState({});

axios.request({ ...optionsParams,
                params: { s: `${movieData.title}`}
             })
      .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
          const traktid = response.data.search[0].traktid;
          const traktidOptions = {
              ...optionsParams,
              params: { t: `${traktid}`
          }
      };
axios.request(traktidOptions).then(function (response) {
    const streamingServices = response.data.streams;
    const streamingServicesSet = streamingServices.map((streams) => ({
        name: streams.name
    }))

setStreamingState(streamingServicesSet);
console.log(streamingState);
```

and I want to return it in the return body with:

```
<div className='streaming' id="streaming">
  <h3 style={{"marginRight" : "10px"}}>Available on: </h3>
  {/* {streamingState.map((streams) => {return(<div>{streams.name}</div>)})} */}
  {streamingState.name}
</div>
```

Does someone mind looking and seeing if you can help?
I have tried multiple things and keep getting this error 'streamingState.map is not a function'

Comment: Did what I can with your code, but it looks like there's at least one missing closing parenthesis/brackets ( more like two or three? )

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error occurs in the line `const [streamingState, setStreamingState] = useState({});`. Here you are defining the type of `streamingState`  to be an object.

`.map` is a function for **arrays only**, and thus trying to map an object will result in an error.

If you would `console.log(streamingState)`, you will be able to see the type, which from the looks of it might be an object. You'll want to change the type in your useState() line to an array of objects ie. `const [streamingState, setStreamingState] = useState([{}])` and make sure that part is working correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I will give this a shot... it certainly makes sense and I appreciate your help

Comment: No problem! There might be a couple other small things that need to be changed but I think that’s the main problem. Just remember console.log is your friend :)

Comment: Legend! as you said, it worked great after a couple of other tweaks, thank you again

Comment: No worries at all. Glad I could help!